# overload operator = in C#. How can i accept other types?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

So a friend was telling me how a game was hacked and how the technique worked. He then asked whats the best way to prevent that kind of attack. The most straight forward way i knew was to A) the shuffle the bits of important value B) hash the values and compare them every time (an int that holds the score or money is likely to be checked rarely).

Then i tried the implementation in C#, i couldnt overload the = operator. How can i do this?

ex code.

```
class EncryptVal <T>
{
    T v;
    public T operator = (T v2)
    {
        //shuffle bits
    }
    public T operator ()()
    {
        //return unshuffle bits
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that .Net code is nevertheless pretty easy to hack.

In most situations you can get the exact source from your IL, and an external debugger (like windbg with SoS extensions) will allow you to easily get examine your "encrypted" instance.

So I think a class like this is a waste of time for a hacker with 5 more minutes to spare.

Comment: lol Groo, i didnt know that. I actually originally ask this question just to see if i could do it in C#. What you just said is probably more then what a basic game hacker would know. I'm actually thinking about hashing the value then compare it. If its not the same, have the game display a joke to the hacker. But this is assuming i make a game in C# or in any language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can encapsulate the value in the class and overload the implicit conversions to and from the class:

```
public class EncryptVal<T> {

    private T _value;

    private EncryptVal(T value) {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator EncryptVal<T>(T value) {
        //shuffle bits
        return new EncryptVal<T>(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator T(EncryptVal<T> value) {
        //unshuffle bits
        return value._value;
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
// implicit conversion from int
EncryptVal<int> e = 42;

// implicit conversion to int
int i = e;
```

Answer (score 13):

You're looking for the `implicit` and `explicit` operator, rather than saying `=`. This allows you to define how things will work when cast implicitly (ie, just an assignment) and explicitly (ie, there's a casting operator).

```
public static implicit operator Type1(Type2 p) {}
public static explicit operator Type1(Type2 p) {}
```

Comment: I think he doesn't want to cast. He wants a container that holds an encrypted value.

Comment: This seems like a pretty elegant way of accomplishing the task in C#. I was going to suggest method accessors or even a value property, but this makes usage far simpler.

Comment: Casting was the wrong word to use. Conversion would have been more accurate. This method will accomplish what you describe.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to overload the assignment operator in C#. [Here's the MSDN documentation on it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w(VS.71).aspx).

You'll have to create your own function for this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you come from C++ where it is very common to write classes that are used like primitive data types. In C# you do things more explicitly.

I would write it as a property or as two methods, eg:

```
class EncryptVal <T>
{
    T v;
    public T Value
    {
      get
      {
        //return unshuffle bits
      }
      set
      {
        //shuffle bits
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your close but no dice. I would need to do o.v = val; instead of o = val;

Comment: Yes, it's like with a Nullable<T>. int i = nullableInt.Value

Answer (score 0):

Dont use = for setting the value. You cant overload assignment.

What you can do is hide it behind a property.

```
int _encyptedValue;
Public int myInt
{
    get
    {
        return Decrypt(_encryptedValue);
    }
    set
    {
         _encryptedValue = Encrypt(value);
    }
}
```

You get to chosse your decryption/encryption

Answer (score 0):

I would go the for implicit/explicit operator overloading for the implementation part.

Probably the explicit one since your conversion does heavy processing, and that it eventually could fail.

I would just add that shuffling bits seems to be only an obfuscation technic that will surely not last long if you have wishfull hackers interested in your game.
You probably need stronger cryptography to protect your data, but more context is needed.